# Parameters for a Hierarchical Multinomial Regression

Tags: logistic, multinomial-distribution, nonparametric, hierarchical-bayesian

I am trying to fit a hierarchical multinomial regression to  cross sectional data. I have around 2000 units with only one observation per unit. I have a binomial response variable and 14 dummy indicator variables. Im using the rhierMnlRwMixture function in the bayesm package  to fit a Hierarchical Multinomial Logit with Mixture
of Normals Heterogeneity  but i'm struggling to choose my parameters: number of normals for the mixture, Z matrix with which betas are built, priors for parameters.

Can anyone guide me as to what I need to take into consideration in choosing these model parameters?

Also, how appropriate is it to use a hierarchical model with only 1 observation per unit? Should I cluster my population first to obtain less units with more observations?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this makes sense but if you were simply solving a gaussian mixture you could use k-means clustering first and estimate an optimal number of components for that. There are many already implemented techniques. Usually, as initial parameters for solving a gaussian mixtures (for example with the EM algorithm), you need an initial guess for the mean, standard deviation and proportion of each cluster. These can all be estimated from the k-means clustering. Something of the sort could work out for you here.

Comment: I actually tried it the other way arounnd. I didnt't look for any clusters and I fitted a Multinomial Hierarchical Bayes and I used the betas as criteria to cluster the population but I think that it wasn't a good idea, beacause there are too many parameters: beta_0, beta_1,...,beta_m  for each individual. Assuming I perform some sort of clustering, the model im fitting still allows for errors which are a mixture of normals and the number of components doesn't necessarily correspond to the number of clusters one inputs! I don't know with what criteria to choose this parameter.